# Eevee Glass Problems with Overlap and Alphas

Tags: rendering, texturing, eevee-render-engine, transparency, glass

im working on a 3D model of a car for my company, and the problem is that the windows (front, lateral, back, etc) of the main car have problems on export and in viewport.

**When you rotate the view around, in some point the glasses loss the effect and become grey or white (only when there are too much glass behind other from our viewpoint)**

i made my research on internet and other forums and the alpha for glass in Eevee have problems
I saw too a post where they say to not have the same material, but i try to, and i run into the same quickly

i did check normals, geometry, hdri, and look at materials blend modes, backface and similar tweaks for glass and i dont know if the problem is from my parameters or its a bug from Eevee

**Here the images for see what i mean:**

https://ibb.co/DgKJXmd (where is the bug)(front passenger window is where you need to look)

https://ibb.co/XDnvgFZ (rotated view a bit from the perspective of image 1, and that weird colour is gone)

sorry for my bad english, hope i didnt make your eyes bleed

**Thx for your time :D**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add image from your shading , i think you missed some nodes

This is what you need :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Same in Evee .

And set alpha for BSDF material to "0"

GL .

Comment: i try to recreate your setup, exactly same parameters, but it makes the same effect.

Update: I pick the materials, and i apply them to prmitives (a flatten box, but a box to keep that inside and double side), nd i think the problem is in the curvature of the the glass in the the car)


The primitives with flat quads works much better than the window already placed, which is triangulated and deformed, so maybe is a geometry problem

But thx so much Salman for the quick answer,it is  very appreciated

Comment: Make a test Scene as simplify scene and handle your problem over there , and make sure what is making this issue , good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was (as the good of Salman said) (I was doing the simplify scene scene when I saw the comment, so perfect)

When retry to do everything the problem was Alpha at high levels, more than 0.4 is when it start to flick with no sense, so:

**SOLUTION**: **Reduce Alpha levels** until you get good transparency, recreate Salman setup, and even without the glass node, Principled BSDF directly to Material Output works the same way (if you want to optimise exports, which is my case)

Thanks aging Salman.
Have a nice day